# Graphite doesn't display any data

Tags: graphite

I'm trying to setup graphite (megacarbon) with Ceres storage.

Right now the default gui graphite-web does not show any data in `Tree / Metrics` However in search I'm able to search for my metrics and it shows some results. But I'm unable to plot any data. Any idea what could be wrong?

Is there some way how to dump graphite config, so that I could see which config graphite actually uses?

```
Tue Jul 15 16:49:22 2014 :: [IndexSearcher] performing initial index load
Tue Jul 15 16:49:22 2014 :: [IndexSearcher] reading index data from /opt/graphite/storage/index
Tue Jul 15 16:49:22 2014 :: [IndexSearcher] index reload took 0.002199 seconds (1143 entries)
Tue Jul 15 16:49:24 2014 :: graphite.wsgi - pid 7979 - reloading search index
Tue Jul 15 16:49:24 2014 :: [IndexSearcher] performing initial index load
Tue Jul 15 16:49:24 2014 :: [IndexSearcher] reading index data from /opt/graphite/storage/index
Tue Jul 15 16:49:24 2014 :: [IndexSearcher] index reload took 0.002313 seconds (1143 entries)
Tue Jul 15 16:49:24 2014 :: find_view query=* local_only=0 matches=0
Tue Jul 15 16:49:24 2014 :: received remote find request: pattern=* from=None until=None local_only=0 format=treejson matches=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late, but ...

In `local_settings.py` or `settings.py`

```
STORAGE_FINDERS = (
 'graphite.finders.ceres.CeresFinder',
)
```

And restart the Apache process.

Comment: Thanks, I've ended up with using Whisper, because I had impression that Ceres is still unstable and documentation is missing.